# Query to get time consuming sql statements in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How can we get information regarding poorly performing sqls(taking too much time for execution)

Does MS SQL server maintains tables/views (Similar to v$sql in Oracle) for storing sql queries.

Answer (score 5):

I Use the SQL Profiler to collect statistic data wich I then can use to nail down where there are need to do some work, tweak indexes and so on.

Here are some tips about monitoring with Profiler:
http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3490086
http://vyaskn.tripod.com/analyzing_profiler_output.htm

Comment: Do we have any SQL query to achieve the same?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have profiler dump the information into a table that you can then use SQL to search.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at sys.dm_exec_query_stats and [this page](http://glennberrysqlperformance.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!45041418ECCAA960!828.entry). SQL Server 2005+ only.